# AWS Control Tower Automation

Tags: aws-control-tower

Is there any document or is there any way to create AWS control towel using APIs or boto3? I'm unable to find any documentation in AWS for automating this process.

or do we have any API to register an OU to control tower?

Comment: Control Tower does not have an IaC aspect as of yet. Would suggest adding a feature request for this.

Answer (score 2):

AWS Control tower currently does not expose any APIs and is only usable via web console. Multi level OU is also not supported at this point (for e.g. Root > Project >> *ThisOUIsNotSupported*), so you can register only top level OUs (e.g. Root >> *ThisOUCanBeRegistered*) using the 'Register OU' button.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Control Tower customers can now programmatically manage controls, also known as guardrails, across their organization at scale.

Have a look at the API Reference Documentation at [**Programmatically manage controls with APIs**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/controltower/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html)

It's not much though.